# How to access `this` from a Closure?

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen

I am passing a Rust closure that acts as a callbck to a JavaScript API as [documented](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/reference/passing-rust-closures-to-js.html) by `wasm-bindgen`. The API stores information in the `this` keyword that can be accessed in the callback.

How can I access the object `this` is pointing to in my Rust closure code?

Comment: Please edit your question to include some code. Writing a [reprex] makes it easier for someone to answer.